# Why isn't NextAuth jwt automatically saved in cookies?

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, jwt

I have two simple authentication callback functions "jwt" and "session" which check if the user object exists and create the session if so.

```
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      if(user) {
        token.id = user.id
      }
      return token
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if(token) {
        session.id = token.id
      }
      return session
    },
  }
```

My issue is, and I have been searching a lot to find information concerning this, why isn't this jwt automatically saved to cookies?

I find that my session is created and I am successfully "logged in", however if I look into my local storage there are no jwt cookies saved.

Do I have to manually save the jwt to my cookies in the jwt callback? Or is the jwt cookie not even required in the case of jwt session strategy? I need jwt cookies because from what I've read about middleware most solutions use cookies and decrypt the jwt to see if the user is logged in, instead of checking the getSession() hook.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to to explain your problem in more detail since I can´t really tell what you already implemented and left out for simplicity sake. I hope this helps you anyway:

The steps to add the cookie look roughly like this:

1. Create / sign a jwt with a npm package like jose or jsonwebtoken
2. Set the header of your response and add your signed jwt to it; return it to the client

```js
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify, JWTVerifyResult } from "jose";

async function setCookie(response, user: {id: number}) {
  const token = await generateJwtToken(user);
  response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [
    `user=${token};` +
      "expires=" + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 86409000).toUTCString() + ";"
  ]);
  response.status(200).json({message: "Successfully set cookie"})
}

async function generateJwtToken(user: { id: number }) {
  return await new SignJWT({id: user.id})
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
    .setIssuedAt()
    .setExpirationTime("24h")
    .sign(new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.YOUR_JWT_TOKEN_ENV_VAR));
}
```

3. Verify the jwt on further requests with the same package as in 1.

```js
export async function verifyJwt(request) {
  const token = request.cookies["yourCustomUser"];
  const verified: JWTVerifyResult = await jwtVerify(
    token,
    new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.YOUR_JWT_TOKEN_ENV_VAR),
  );
  verified.payload.status = 200;
  return verified.payload;
}
```

In addition to that you might wanna add sameSite=Strict, secure or path=/. For further information you should have a look at [developers.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)
Also make sure to add error handling for expired Jwts etc.